# How to deal with matrices in C using dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c, matrix, memory-management

I was trying to run a simulation in which I need to fill three matrices of size "2 x iterations", this is (iterations=)10^8 columns and 2 rows. I also work with a vector t of size 10^8. Using dynamic memory allocation I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define T 10000
#define dt 0.0001
#define iterations (T/dt)

/*(more code)*/
int main(){
  int i, j;
  double *t;
  double (*x)[2], (*y)[2], (*c)[2];

  t=(double *) malloc((iterations-1)*sizeof(double));
  x=(double (*)[2]) malloc((2*(iterations))*sizeof(double));
  y=(double (*)[2]) malloc((2*(iterations))*sizeof(double));
  c=(double (*)[2]) malloc((2*(iterations))*sizeof(double));

  for(i=0; i=1; i++){
   x[i][0]=50+500*i;
   y[i][0]=300;
   c[i][0]=15;
  }

  for(j=0; j<=iterations-2; j++){
   t[j+1]=t[j]+dt;
   /*(more code)*/
   printf("%G %G %G %G %G %G\n",x[0][j+1],x[1][j+1],y[0][j+1],y[1][j+1],c[0][j+1],c[1][j+1]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Is the dynamic memory allocation correctly written? I mean, do I really have a vector t of size "iterations" and the three matrices of size "2 x iterations"?

And, if I want to fill each component of the matrices, for example I want a 50 in the position (1,4) of the matrix x, then do I have to write x[1][4]=50? (Like in the first "for".)

The problem is that executing the program I get an error: segmentation fault. Then, using a debugger I get the following:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

x[0][0]=50

Comment: Any errors and optimization aside, simply using two variables `x1` and `x2` would improve readability a lot.

Comment: 1) Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends. 2) Don't use magic numbers. 3) This is no code review service. What is your **specific** problem? 4) Note: `sizeof(*x)` etc. gives the size of a single entry in the array as always.

Comment: Should I write two vectors instead of one matrix? I want a really optimum code since I am working with a huge amount of data and large numbers. At first I wrote the same simulation in Octave, but putting specific values for the parameters made the program hang after it has run about 8 hours...
The specific problem is that executing the program I get the error segmentation fault ('core' denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic way to allocate a matrix:

```
double **mat_init(int n_rows, int n_cols)
{
    double **m;
    int i;
    m = (double**)malloc(n_rows * sizeof(double*));
    for (i = 0; i < n_rows; ++i)
        m[i] = (double*)calloc(n_cols, sizeof(double));
    return m;
}    
void mat_destroy(int n_rows, double **m)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n_rows; ++i) free(m[i]);
    free(m);
}
```

You can also do this:

```
double **mat_init2(int n_rows, int n_cols)
{
    double **m;
    int i;
    m = (double**)malloc(n_rows * sizeof(double*));
    m[0] = (double*)calloc(n_rows * n_cols, sizeof(double));
    for (i = 1; i < n_rows; ++i)
        m[i] = m[i-1] + n_cols;
    return m;
}    
void mat_destroy2(double **m)
{
    free(m[0]); free(m);
}
```

For both methods above, you can use `matrix[row][col]` to access a cell. Sometimes, you may prefer to allocate a single array and use `matrix[row*n_cols+col]` to access a cell.

BTW, I am sure someone will say "don't use cast", but there are benefits of using cast – that is off-topic.

Comment: I'd check the return values of malloc and calloc (not to start a religion war, but I'd also prefer `double **m = malloc(n_rows * sizeof *m);`, but yes, it's OT) and the pointer passed to the destroy functions, because, while it's OK to free a NULL pointer, it's a runtime error to dereference a NULL pointer (m[i] or m[0]).

Answer (score 1):

> I mean, do I really have a vector t of size "iterations"

```
t=(double *) malloc((iterations-1)*sizeof(double));
                            ^^^
```

Since you subtract one, the answer is no.

> .... and the three matrices of size "2 x iterations"?

Well - yes you have three matrices of size "2 x iterations". However, what you have is equivalent to:

```
double m[iterations][2];
```

so you have "iterations" rows and 2 columns.

Remember to **always** check for "out of memory", i.e.

```
p = malloc(....);
if (p == NULL)
{
    printf("out of mem\n");
    return -1;
}
```

So you access it like:

```
m[0][0]
m[0][1]
m[1][0]
m[1][1]
m[2][0]
m[2][1]
m[3][0]
......
```

Comment: OP wants _"10^8 columns and 2 rows"_ but declares `double (*x)[2]` and then allocates `x=(double (*)[2]) malloc((2*(iterations))*sizeof(double));`...

Comment: Thanks! @4386427, you mean `double m[2][iterations]`, right?
The problem is that I get a segmentation fault error and using a debugger I get the following:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
x[0][0]=50;
And I do not know what is wrong...

Comment: @S.Proa - No, I actually mean what is written. You should not have problems `x[0][0]` unless you are of memory. See updated answer.

Comment: Wow, ok! Then, do I have to declare `double (*x)[iterations]` and allocate `x=(double(*)[2]) malloc((2*(iterations))*sizeof(double));`?
Or it is better the following:
`double **x;`
`x=(double **)malloc(2*sizeof(double*));`
`for(i=0; i<2; i++){`
`x[i]=(double*)malloc(iterations*sizeof(double));`
`}`

Comment: @S.Proa yes the first proposal should be fine. Except for the cast but just remove the cast in front of malloc.

Comment: @4386427 What do you exact mean? I try it and it doesn't work. Well, never mind, the second option works properly!